# C#, WinForms ListBox - Programatically setting DisplayMember property - can text be added?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am working in WinForms with a ListBox.  I have questions about the `DisplayMember` property.

If I understand correctly - if I do not provide a `DisplayMember` property then the ListBox uses the objects `ToString()` method.  However if I specify `DisplayMember` then the ListBox will show the specified property of the objects in the collection.

However, is it possible to add some static text?

What I mean is, if my Property returns a first name such as "Dave", is there a way for me to prefix this with "First Name: Dave" through using the DisplayMember property or some other means?

I ask because the collection of objects I am working with is from a class I don't have control over - therefore I can't easily create a new property or override the `ToString()` method.

I thought briefly about extending the class and providing my own overridden `ToString()` method.  However in my case I would need the ability to cast the parent class to the child class (which is not possible).  I thought shortly about writing a static method that would accept the parent class as a parameter, copy its contents and return the child class but I just don't know if that is considered clean and best practice.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you try? give us some codes.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet other than reading documentation.  There really isn't any code to show or share at this point.  I did share some other possible approaches but expressed not being sure if they were best practices.  This is a general question about how to change the behavior of what is shown in a ListBox after a binding occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a separate wrapper object that you'll use. You can make that object generic and use it on every place where you have that same problem. What I'll do is something like that.

```
namespace Demo
{
    using System;

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set;}
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemWrapper<T>
    {
        public T Item { get; private set; }
        public string DisplayMember { get; private set; }

        public ItemWrapper(T item, Func<T, string> displayFactory) {
            if (item == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }

            if (displayFactory == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("displayFactory");
            }

            this.Item = item;
            this.DisplayMember = displayFactory(item);
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return this.DisplayMember;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is just an example and should be removed
        /// </summary>
        public static void Example() {
            var person1 = new Person() { FirstName = "Johny", LastName = "Bravo" };
            var person2 = new Person() { FirstName = "Johny2", LastName = "Bravo" };
            var person3 = new Person() { FirstName = "Johny3", LastName = "Bravo" };

            var item1 = new ItemWrapper<Person>(person1, p => "First Name: " + p.FirstName);
            var item2 = new ItemWrapper<Person>(person2, delegate(Person p) { return "First Name: " + p.FirstName; });
            var item3 = new ItemWrapper<Person>(person3, DisplayFactory);
        }

        private static string DisplayFactory(Person p) {
            return "First Name" + p.FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say that you have a form with a ListBox on it. Then you can use it like that:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var p1 = new Person() {FirstName = "Johny", LastName = "Bravo"};
            var p2 = new Person() {FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Flo"};
            var list = new List<ItemWrapper<Person>>
            {
                new ItemWrapper<Person>(p1, p => p.FirstName),
                new ItemWrapper<Person>(p2, p => p.FirstName)
            };
            var bs = new BindingSource(list, "Item");
            this.listBox1.DataSource = bs;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var person = this.listBox1.SelectedValue as Person;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mcl, this is very helpful. I am going to have some follow up questions after doing some testing and documentation reading.  I don't have much experience with delegates or lambda expressions and want to read some official documentation before accepting your answer.

Comment: Can you explain the syntax of `var item = new ItemWrapper<Person>(p, p => "First Name: " + p.FirstName);` to me? Specifically when I do `Person p = new Person("Dave");` and then `var item = new ItemWrapper<Person>(p, p => "First Name: " + p.Name);` I receive a compile error, _A local variable named p cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to p, which is already used in parent or current scope to denote something else_.  If I change this to `var item = new ItemWrapper<Person>(p, Person => "First Name: " + p.Name);` it works and I don't understand why.

Comment: Ok my mistake, that's because I've written the script in place without actually compiling it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Lambdas are methods that are defined and used inline. This is like defining a method and passing it (the method not its return value) to some consumer. For better explanation check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Thanks again, learned a lot from reading and your example / clarification.  For extra credit - am I able to use `myListBox.ValueMember` so that the item returned by `myListBox.SelectedItem` is `T`?  In my testing when I utilize a collection and add objects of the `ItemWrapper<Person>` to the collection, even though I set `myListBox.ValueMember = 'Item'` (property of ItemWrapper class that contains T), I am still returned a `ItemWrapper<Person>` object.  Can I do something to be returned just the Person object?